# Operate on attributes of data.frames stored in a list using lapply

Tags: r, attributes, dataframe, lapply

Consider the following:

```
df <- list(df1 = data.frame(a.1 = 1, b..2 = 2), df2 = data.frame(c.1 = 3, d...4 = 5, e..3 = 8))
## $df1
##   a.1 b..2
## 1   1    2

## $df2
##   c.1 d...4 e..3
## 1   3     5    8

names(df[[1]])
## [1] "a.1"  "b..2"
```

Now, for example, I would like to remove the dotes out of the data frames' names so the output will be

```
## $df1
##   a1 b2
## 1   1    2

## $df2
##   c1 d4 e3
## 1   3     5    8
```

Obvioulsy the following won't work

```
lapply(names(df), function(x) gsub("[.]", "", x))
```

Neither will this

```
lapply(df[attributes(df)$names], function(x) gsub("[.]", "", x))
```

a `for` loop works though

```
for(i in 1:length(df)){names(df[[i]]) <- gsub("[.]", "", names(df[[i]]))}
## $df1
##   a1 b2
## 1  1  2

## $df2
##   c1 d4 e3
## 1  3  5  8
```

## Edit

@jdharrison solution is very nice, but i was looking to find a way to operate only on the attributes rather on the whole data set (like in the `for` loop), something like

```
df2 <- list(a..1 = 2, b..3 = 5)
names(df2) <- lapply(names(df2), function(x) gsub("[.]", "", x))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
lapply(df, function(x){ 
  `names<-`(x, gsub("[.]", "",names(x)))
}
)

> lapply(df, function(x){ `names<-`(x, gsub("[.]", "",names(x)))})
$df1
  a1 b2
1  1  2

$df2
  c1 d4 e3
1  3  5  8
```

Comment: That is nice, So I guess I'll have to do something like  `df <- lapply(df, function(x) { `names<-` (x, gsub("[.]", "", names(x)))})` in order to save the changes. Does it mean that I'm copying the whole data set instead of just operating on the names like in a for loop?

Comment: You would need to ask someone more knowledgeable regarding the internals on that issue.

Comment: I've edited the original post, thanks for that great trick though